# Magento 2 upgradeSchema.php Not Adding the Column on Database

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am trying to add column 'address' on existing upgradeSchema.php, but it not worked.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    namespace Testing\Test\Setup;


    use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

    class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {

        public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();

            if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
                $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                    $setup->getTable('testing_test_item'),
                    'description',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Item Description'
                    ]
                ); 
                $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                    $setup->getTable('testing_test_item'),
                    'address',
                    [
                        'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                        'nullable' => true,
                        'comment' => 'Item Address'
                    ]
                );
            }
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Module.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Testing_Test" setup_version="1.0.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Share your `module.xml` code as well and
Have you run `setup:di:compile` command?

Comment: yes, check the module.xml code (edited question)

Comment: Hi @RahulSingh remove (or) comment version condition and execute deploy commands

Comment: by removing module schema version entry from setup_module table worked and rest code used the same as in question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to database and find `setup_module` table and delete your module from database.

Replace your code with below one

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('testing_test_item'),
                'description',
                [
                    'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Item Description'
                ]
            ); 
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('testing_test_item'),
                'address',
                [
                    'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Item Address'
                ]
            );
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Testing_Test" setup_version="1.0.2">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
 </module>
</config>
```

> Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade

I hope it helps!

Comment: by removing module schema version from setup_module table worked and rest code used the same as in question, thanks

Comment: @Rahul Singh Thanks for accepting as answer i have minor changed in `if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {` condition but any way your problem is solved ;)

Comment: @Rahul Singh if you think my answer is good then +1 vote so it is useful to other user.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already installed your module and you run this script it will not work.

check `setup_module` table in which version installed. if version `1.0.2` then change it to `1.0.3`

You have to change module version in `module.xml` as `setup_version="1.0.3"` after
 run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` check the column in table.

Or

You can also use by delete module row from `setup_version` without changing anything.

it will be reflected.

Comment: done the same, not worked added module.xml code in question

Comment: @RahulSingh have you tried which version in table?

Comment: by removing module schema version entry from setup_module table worked and rest code used the same as in question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be the version installed is already **`1.0.1`** try changing it to **`1.0.2`**

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
```

Comment: by removing module schema version entry from setup_module table worked and rest code used the same as in question, thanks